# How to run Jest-Puppeteer test in multiple files

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, e2e-testing, web-testing, webtest

I am using jest-puppeteer to run my webtests. If I am running my tests all defined in one file, everything works perfectly.

```
describe('user', () => {

    jest.setTimeout(12000);

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 2000});
        await page.goTo('http://localhost:3000');
    });

    it('test 1', async () => {
        //my test steps
    });

    it('test 2', async () => {
        //my test steps
    });

});
```

However, if I am running each test in its own file, I get an error.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addExpectationResult' of undefined
```

FILE 1

```
describe('user', () => {

    jest.setTimeout(12000);

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 2000});
        await page.goTo('http://localhost:3000');
    });

    it('test 1', async () => {
        //my test steps
    });

});
```

FILE 2

```
describe('user', () => {

    jest.setTimeout(12000);

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 2000});
        await page.goTo('http://localhost:3000');
    });

    it('test 2', async () => {
        //my test steps
    });

});
```

Interestingly, if I add a console.log('some statement') as first step in test2, everything works again. That's why I think it might be a timing issue. I am running my tests sequentially, i.e. `jest --runInBand`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

As you say i agree that the problem is the async sequentially, as explained in [that github bugreport](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5922) in Patrick Hulce  answer:

> FWIW I also ran into this and was led to this issue. Only happened in
>   CI when an async test timed out but the underlying action continued
>   until after the test suite finished (and I'm guessing the callback
>   tried to add the result of the expectation). I could never get it to
>   happen locally though.

so probably your error is inside "//my test steps" where you manipulate something in both the test that you can/need manipulate before running the async process.